# Pandas: Value With Greatest Quantity Resampled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame  df

```
                       value    quantity  
2020-01-02 08:50:03    A         20           
2020-01-02 08:52:39    B         29                   
2020-01-02 08:54:51    C         30                   
2020-01-02 08:55:03    C         20                   
2020-01-02 08:56:43    A         20                   
2020-01-02 08:59:59    B         10 
2020-01-02 09:02:01    A         29
2020-01-02 09:03:29    B         27                   
2020-01-02 09:06:51    C         30                   
2020-01-02 09:07:03    C         20                   
2020-01-02 09:07:43    A         33                   
2020-01-02 09:09:59    B         10
```

I want to resample my DataFrame every T minutes (10 minutes in this example). And return the value that has the highest quantity. In the above example, I want to return the following:

```
                       value    quantity  
2020-01-02 08:50:00    C         50
2020-01-02 09:00:00    A         62
```

My current solution works but is slow due to redundant computations.

```
def get_value_with_max_qty(df_rl):
    """ Returns the value and total quantity of the value with max qty
    Args:
         df_rl: A pandas rolling object
    Returns:
         A pandas series
    """
    gper = df_rl.groupby(df_rl.value).quantity.sum()
    return pd.Series([gper.idxmax(), gper.max()])
```

Then, I run:

```
df.resample('10T', label='right',closed='left').apply(get_value_with_max_qty)
```

Is there a way to make my code faster and more memory-efficient without using groupby in an apply method?

Answer (score 0):

Three observations:

1. `resample` is often found to be slower compared to `pd.Grouper`
2. using an indexing method is often faster than `idxmax`
3. avoid nesting `groupby` if possible

I benchmark an alternative method, `largest_quantity_proposal`, to yours, `largest_quantity_baseline`. This one computes the group specific quantity aggregates at once as opposed to using `groupby` within `resample`. Both produce the same result:

```
>>> largest_quantity_baseline(df)
                     0   1
datetime
2020-01-02 09:00:00  C  50
2020-01-02 09:10:00  A  62
>>> largest_quantity_proposal(df)
datetime             value
2020-01-02 09:00:00  C        50
2020-01-02 09:10:00  A        62
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

For 1,000 repetitions, the suggested method takes on average 2.9ms vs. 4ms for the baseline method on my machine, i.e., it's roughly 30% faster.

```py
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from io import StringIO

def largest_quantity_baseline(df):
    def get_value_with_max_qty(df_rl):
        gper = df_rl.groupby(df_rl.value).quantity.sum()
        return pd.Series([gper.idxmax(), gper.max()])
    return df.resample('10T', label='right', closed='left').apply(get_value_with_max_qty)

def largest_quantity_proposal(df):
    test = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='10Min', label='right', closed='left'),'value'])['quantity'].sum()
    return test[test == test.groupby('datetime').transform('max')]

# sample data
df = """  
datetime,value,quantity
2020-01-02 08:50:03,A,20
2020-01-02 08:52:39,B,29
2020-01-02 08:54:51,C,30
2020-01-02 08:55:03,C,20
2020-01-02 08:56:43,A,20
2020-01-02 08:59:59,B,10
2020-01-02 09:02:01,A,29
2020-01-02 09:03:29,B,27
2020-01-02 09:06:51,C,30
2020-01-02 09:07:03,C,20
2020-01-02 09:07:43,A,33
2020-01-02 09:09:59,B,10
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep=',', engine='python',parse_dates=['datetime'], index_col='datetime')

# check result for correctness
largest_quantity_baseline(df)
largest_quantity_proposal(df)

# benchmark tests
num_runs = 1000

duration = timeit.Timer(lambda: largest_quantity_baseline(df)).timeit(number = num_runs)
print(duration/num_runs)

duration = timeit.Timer(lambda: largest_quantity_proposal(df)).timeit(number = num_runs)
print(duration/num_runs)
```